# How to eliminate rows and columns of matrices?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I would like to create an operation that checks if the elements of the row are 0 and eliminate the respective row and column associated with the row matrix. If if the lines have at least one non-zero element, then the matrix is copied as is. See figure below [image]
Suppose I have a list of matrices that increases in size, as for example

```
    list={{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{0, 0, 0, 
   0}, {1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}}, {{0, 1, 1, 1, 
   1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1,
    0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
   0}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
   0}}, {{0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 
   1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
   0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
   0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
   0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
   1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}}}
```

Could someone help me apply the rule to that list?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that in your sample list all the elements of all the diagonals are 0 (check it with Diagonal /@ list), so your output would be empty for each matrix

Comment: @Fraccalo I edited the list for a case where there is no 0 in the main diagonal of the 3x3 matrix

Answer (score 8):

```
ClearAll[dropZRC1, dropZRC2, dropZRC3]
dropZRC1 = Module[{p = Flatten@Position[SparseArray[#]["MatrixColumns"], {__}]}, 
   #[[p,p]]] &;

dropZRC2 = Module[{p = Flatten@Position[#, {___, Except[0], ___}]}, #[[p, p]]] &;

dropZRC3 = Module[{p = Position[#, {0 ..}]}, Nest[Transpose[Delete[#, p]] &, #, 2]] &;
```

For OP's `list` all three methods give the same results:

```
And @@ (dropZRC1[#] == dropZRC2[#] == dropZRC3[#] & /@ list)
```

> True

```
Row[MatrixForm /@ list] // TeXForm
```

> $\tiny\begin{array}{ccc}
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccc}
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
>  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \end{array}$

```
Row[MatrixForm /@ dropZRC1 /@ list] // TeXForm
```

> $\tiny\begin{array}{ccc}
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  0 & 1 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \end{array}$

Comment: Cool idea `p = Position[#, {0 ..}]`!

Comment: Nice use of SparseArray.  But why `"MatrixColumns"` instead of `"AdjacencyLists"`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, that works too (totally forgot about it and went with the first property that gave what i needed:)

Answer (score 6):

I would do it this way: 1) find the position on the elements equal to $1$ on the diagonal, 2) select the corresponding rows and columns.

```
operate[mat_] := With[{pos = Flatten@Position[Diagonal@mat, 1]}, mat[[pos, pos]]]
operate@{{1, 0}, {1, 0}} 
(* {{1}} *)
operate@{{1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}
(* {{1, 1}, {0, 1}} *)
operate@{{0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0}}
(* {{1, 0}, {1, 1}} *)
operate/@list
(* {{}, {{1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}} *)
```

**Edit** The question has been changed (replacing "diagonal" with row) so of course this answer no longer makes sense...

Answer (score 1):

A bit messy, but it should work:

```
process[m_] := Block[{t = m, temp, ind},
  temp = Position[Diagonal[t], 0];
  ind = temp - Range[0, Length@temp - 1];
  ((t = Transpose[Drop[Transpose[Drop[t, #]], #]]) & /@ ind)[[-1]]
  ]


process[{{1, 0}, {1, 0}}]
```

> {{1}}

```
process[{{1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}}]
```

> {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}